# d3js call animations on an object, enter/append is not a function

Tags: javascript, animation, d3.js, transition

D3 newbie here:

I'm returning an object p

Object {name: xxx, age: yyy.. } etc.

Is there any way to animate this object using transition? Anytime I call transition I get p.enter or p.append is not a function.

Here's the code:

```
function moveUp(p) {
            if (!p.children) {
                 p.enter().append("dvc").transition().duration(2000).attr('transform','translate(200,200)');
            }
        }
```

Can someone explain this to me? Thanks!

Comment: Try to make a fiddle then we could do something on it.

Comment: I edited the post to hopefully give a clearer idea of what's going on. I'm using data pulled from a private database so I'm not sure how to put that on jsfiddle!

Comment: By looking at your code, we can clearly know that p is a object, how can we call enter method on object, to animate any element first we have to select the element and to call enter/exit method we should call data method. Seems like you haven't read documentation. Read this Doc https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Selections

Comment: As I've understood it I can use:

e.g. d3.selectAll('p').transition().duration(2000).attr('transform','translate(500,20000)')   to animate the html but I was just trying to understand how I'd work with something that's not tagged in html or how I'd go about tagging it. Apologies, still trying to digest the general idea

Comment: What do you mean by "tagged in the HTML"? In general, you don't animate objects, you animate D3 selections. So `p` in your code needs to be a D3 selection for this to work.

Answer (score 0):

.enter() needs to be called on a selection.

```
var foo = d3.selectAll('foo')
```

Once you have a selection you then call the .data() method

```
foo.data(p)
```

THEN you use enter, append, transition, etc...

```
foo.data(p).enter().append('dvc').....
```